# White noise in headphones after returning from suspend when laptop is plugged in 220v

Tags: 16.04, sound, suspend, power-management, headphones

I have a laptop **asus zenbook pro ux501vw** with **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**. When I first turn on laptop, headphones work fine no matter is it charging or not . But if I suspend laptop, after I login back, I have a white noise in headphones which disappears if I take out power cable and appears again if I connect it. Rebooting helps until first time I suspend my machine. 
I assume it shouldn't be a hardware problem, because everything works well, if not suspending computer. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

---

Btw, I checked with another sockets and another headphones - the same

Comment: This is most likely a hardware problem in your laptop's power supply or battery charging system -- some filtering component is no longer up to the maximum voltage from the 240V source.  Despite appearing only after a suspend, it's most likely a hardware component failing to fully reset after waking the computer.  I've seen similar problems in devices I've owned, and they only appeared when the battery was fully charged -- which is likely to be the case after a suspend with power connected.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
i checked with low battery now - same issue.